# Plot SHAP values in waterfall and beeswarm plots

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, shap

I am working on binary classification using random forest. However, am trying to use SHAP to explain the model predictions. However, I keep getting the below error. I am following the tutorial [here](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/machine-learning/shap-explain-machine-learning-model-predictions-using-game-theoretic-approach)

```
import shap
explainer = shap.Explainer(rf_boruta)  #pass my model
shap_values = explainer(ord_test_t) #pass my test dataset
sample_idx = 15
shap_vals = explainer.shap_values(ord_test_t.iloc[sample_idx:sample_idx+1])
print("Base Value : ", explainer.expected_value)
print()
print("Shap Values for Sample %d : "%sample_idx, shap_vals)
print("\n")
print("Prediction From Model                            : ", rf_boruta.predict(ord_test_t.iloc[15:16]))
print("Prediction From Adding SHAP Values to Base Value : ", explainer.expected_value + shap_vals.sum())
```

I get an error as shown below

```
>       8 print("\n")
>       9 print("Prediction From Model                            : ", rf_boruta.predict(ord_test_t.iloc[sample_idx:sample_idx+1]))
> ---> 10 print("Prediction From Adding SHAP Values to Base Value : ", explainer.expected_value + shap_vals.sum())
> 
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

When I tried another tutorial [here](https://notebook.community/slundberg/shap/notebooks/general/Explainable%20AI%20with%20Shapley%20Values), I got another error

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_boruta,ord_test_t)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(ord_test_t)
sample_ind = 0
shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[sample_ind],ord_test_t.iloc[sample_ind])


TypeError: waterfall() got multiple values for argument 'max_display'
```

Later, when I change it to default, I get another error as shown below

```
> ---> 46     base_values = shap_values.base_values
>      47 
>      48     features = shap_values.data
> 
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'base_values'
```

**update - another code tried**

```
row_to_show = 5
data_for_prediction = ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show]  # use 1 row of data here. Could use multiple rows if desired
data_for_prediction_array = data_for_prediction.values.reshape(1, -1)
rf_boruta.predict_proba(data_for_prediction_array)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_boruta)
# Calculate Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data_for_prediction)
shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.expected_value,shap_values,data_for_prediction)
```

Comment: You probably want `shap_vals` to be a numpy array instead of a `list`. Or use `sum(shap_values)` instead.

Comment: @QuantumMecha - I updated my code to include few more attempts that I tried. I am using a tree based model. Can you let me know how can I make it work? Can you please write it as answer? So, it can help a beginner like me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error callback tells you what the problem is:

```
10 print("Prediction From Adding SHAP Values to Base Value : ", explainer.expected_value + shap_vals.sum())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

So instead of calling `shap_vals.sum()` on your list, get the sum in a way that **is** supported, like using the built-in `sum` function:

```
print("Prediction From Adding SHAP Values to Base Value : ", explainer.expected_value + sum(shap_vals))
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. if you look at the update in my post (at the bottom), I tried another approach and that also gave the same error - `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'base_values'`. Do you know what is the mistake please?

Comment: I can't see where you are calling `.base_values` in the code you have posted, so its hard to fix without a minimal reproducible example. But you can probably work it out yourself just by reading the error. It tells you what the error is and where it occurred. If it occurred in a piece of code you haven't written, you may have to work backwards to work out where your last bit of code calls that code, and then fix it.